# Color button using css html

Tags: html, css, buttonclick, linkbutton, buttoncolor

i have code html

```
<button onclick=location=URL>Refresh</button>
```

how is code given css color?for example as below

CSS code `

```
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button2 {background-color: #008CBA;} /* Blue */
```

`
in html

```
<button class="button button2">Refresh</button>
```

but if implemented in this code

```
<button onclick=location=URL>Refresh</button>
```

an error occurs

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `onclick=location=URL` is not valid HTML, and the `.` at the start of `.button {` means it looks for something with the class "button", not the button element.

Comment: "an error occurs" - What error? How are you trying to implement the first code in the second code? Read [ask]. Provide a real [mcve]. Tell us the *defaults* of the problem.

Comment: onClick is deprecated, use a listener instead!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you must change 2 things:

- atribute onclick:
  you mus have this: `"` around the javascript. like

```
<button onclick="location=URL" >Refresh</button>
```

- if you like to use style with .button, you must add atribute `class="button"`. like this:

```
<button onclick="location=URL" class="button" >Refresh</button>
```

**or,** you can use other think in style: instead of `.button{ ... }`, use `button{ ... }`.

Comment: I mean like this. thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick attribute is wrong. You need to use `window.location.href` or `window.location.reload();`
Here is the documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/location.

Also, if you want to add css to html and you don't know how to do, you can check this https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_howto.asp

Here is a working code :

```css
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;/* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button2 {
    background-color: #008CBA;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button2" onclick="window.location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74922452/color-button-using-css-html';">Refresh</button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

onclick is deprecated and hard to read.
Consider to use a listener to your button!

The code to refresh a page is `window.location.reload();`

```js
    let btn_01;
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onReady);
    function onReady(){
        btn_01 = document.getElementById("button_1");
        btn_01.addEventListener("click",click_1);
    }
    function click_1(){
        window.location.reload();
    }
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button2 {background-color: #008CBA;} /* Blue */
```

```html
<button id="button_1" class="button button2">Refresh</button>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Answer (score -1):

I can't see how you are using the `onclick`. but something is wrong here:

```html
<button onclick=location=URL>Refresh</button>
```

Parenthesis are missing. Maybe try something along the line of this

```html
<button onclick="location.href='../'">
```

Comment: can this code <button onclick=location=URL>Refresh</button> be given css?